# android: Call public methods of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity "USBCommunicationManager" and a class "Helper". At some point "Helper" starts the Activity (a is the MainActivity passed to "Helper"):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(a, USBCommunicationManager.class);
a.startActivity(intent);
```

Now "Helper" needs to call a public method of the started "USBCommunicationManager".

Is that bad practice and how is this possible?

Comment: In a nutshell you have to use activity+interface or activity+broadcastReceiver to call methods inside activity.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm an android beginner and sadly don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you a simple example how to "call a public method" in activity.

First you need to add in `manifest` to your activity

```
  <activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

Then inside `Helper.class` initialize some custom actions

```
public static final String SOME_ACTION1 = "some_action1"
public static final String SOME_ACTION2 = "some_action2"

private void someAction(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(a, USBCommunicationManager.class);
    intent.setAction(SOME_ACTION1)
    a.startActivity(intent);//this calls onNewIntent method in launched activity
}
```

In `USBCommunicationManager` override `onNewIntent`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String action = intent.getAction()

   //now you can check this action and use desired method
}
```

But i recomended to read about `BroadcastReceiver` because with this solution you can accidentally launch activity. But using broadcast you just unregister it on activity destroy and don't worries about activity restarting.

Answer (score -1):

Call another class method by creating object of that class

```html
USBCommunicationManager ucm= new USBCommunicationManager();
ucm.methodName();
```

Comment: This is not concerns to activity classes